# How to give a variable a string from a div with a .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

been lurking for a while , couldn't find a solution to this one though , so i beg your pardon if this is a repost,
the thing is ,I want to make my <'div>s clickable in away that when i click on it , they return the string inside <'p> and assign it to the variable in my Jscript.
tried few methods .. i really need help!

here is my JS code:

```
var userChoice = $('div#select').click(function(){ 
    $(this).effect('highlight' , { color: "rgba(36,117,203,0.6)" } , 'slow' , 500);
       userChoice = (this,'<div id="select"></div>');
       alert("Your choice:" + " " + userChoice);
});
```

here is the html :

```
   <div class="rps"><p>Play Rock Scissors Paper!</p>
     <div id="select"><p>rock</p></div>
     <div id="select"><p>paper</p></div>
     <div id="select"><p>scissors</p></div>
     <div id="result"><p>result:</p></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: ID's should be unique......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes instead of duplicate ID's and use `$(this).text()` in your jQuery function (if there were other elements inside each div, you could use `.children('p')` or `.find('p')` instead):

```
$('.select').click(function(){ 
   $(this).effect('highlight' , { color: "rgba(36,117,203,0.6)" } , 'slow' , 500);
   $('#result').text('result: ' + $(this).text());
});
```

With your HTML as:

```
<div class="rps"><p>Play Rock Scissors Paper!</p>
   <div class="select"><p>rock</p></div>
   <div class="select"><p>paper</p></div>
   <div class="select"><p>scissors</p></div>
   <div id="result"><p>result:</p></div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/YgEZM/4/)

Answer (score 0):

- Use classes. Your HTML must be like this:

  ```
  <div class="rps">
     <p>Play Rock Scissors Paper!</p>
     <div class="select">
      <p>rock</p>
     </div>
     <div class="select">
      <p>paper</p>
     </div>
     <div class="select">
      <p>scissors</p>
     </div>
    <div id="result">
      <p>result:</p>
    </div>
  ```
- The way you're trying to finding text in `p` wont work. It must be

  ```
  userChoice = $("p", this).text(); //find "p" inside this
  ```
- Your click function must be like this :

  ```
   $('.select').click(function () {
       $(this).effect('highlight', {
         color: "rgba(36,117,203,0.6)"
       }, 'slow', 500);
       userChoice = $("p", this).text();
       $("p","#result").text("result : "+ userChoice);
       alert("Your choice:" + " " + userChoice);
   });
  ```
- And here's your demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/KDm5W

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery .text() function:

```
$('div .select').click(function(){ 
    alert("Your choice:" + " " + $(this).text());   
    return $(this).text()  ;     
});
```

Also, remember you can only use an id once, otherwise use classes. Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tgWUX/